# Unity2d: return to previous application on button click

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there a way of returning back to my previous game application when I close unity/close game application on button press. Basically I have a scene with a button in it, if the player press the button, it will bring them to a new level (scene 1). This is where I want to save this scene (scene 2) using something like playerprefs to keep tabs on it so that if I close the game application, or close unity and then I re-open and play the application (regardless of what scene I am in) the game should automatically bring me back to scene 2. Is it possible to return to previous application (even if I close the application or game) on button click?
So if the button is clicked on, and I exit out of the application and or game, then re open it  and play the game then it should automatically bring me back to the scene I exited out of (scene 2)

Comment: It's certainly possible to return the game back to the same state it was in when it was closed, but as to returning to previous application, I doubt that, but it will depend on what platform we are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

When ever application quit event is called, Save current scene as player preference.

```
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

 void quitGame()
{
    Scene currentScene =  SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("lastSceneName",currentScene.name);
    Application.Quit();
}
```

above code will save the name of current scene at time of application quit.

Now when you restart your game and your scene(0) is loaded. call following method in Start() or Awake() function.

```
void loadLastScene()
{
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("isFirstTime") == 0) //this is to make sure this chunk of code doen't run on the very first usage.
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("isFirstTime", 1);
    }
    else if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("isFirstTime") == 1)
    {
    SceneManager.LoadScene(PlayerPrefs.GetString("lastSceneName"));
    }
}
```

Code not tested.

Comment: Why use `PlayerPrefs.SetInt("isFirstTime", 1);`?  Won't that affect functionality the *next time* game is started?  Why not just store this flag in an instance variable?

Comment: But if you quit the app again and then re-open it, the scene won't be loaded.

Comment: Ok Let me explain,
When application will run very first time, 'PlayerPrefs.GetInt("isFirstTime");' will return '0' and condition will be false so Game will proceed as in sequence but when the game will be started second time, 'PlayerPrefs.GetInt("isFirstTime");' will return 1 and previously saved scene will be loaded directly. Assuming game was closed using 'quitGame' method. Otherwise there should be another exceptional handling condition.

Comment: Yes, you were right. I had to edit. There were logical errors